# append or prepend table row from ajax reply jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been making a webmail client, The problem I have came accross now has the aim of prepend new content at the top of a list and remove any removed items within the list and append any messages to the end to make up the page count. I have been trying to do this in 1 function win jquery

each table row has a unique ID which I submit with a $.post() along with information on what filters are active. I can do this OK. The problem I am having is turning the reply into the desired outcome.

The reply consists of 2 tables. with IDs append and prepend. As you may have guessed I want to take the rows from the append table and append them to the end of the displayed table and prepend the rows from the prepend table to the start of the displayed table. then a div with ID remove with a CSV format of table row IDs to be removed. I am able to divide each part into its septate var but I am a little stuck after that.

the JQUERY I currently have is

```
function getfld() {
var ids = $.map($('#MailList tbody tr'), function(elt){return elt.id;});
var curfld = $('#CurDis').val();
var srtord = $('#srtord').val();
var srtitm = $('#srtitm').val();
$.post("index.php?f=1&a=mail&g=lsmsgs&c=" + curfld, {filter: srtitm, fdire: srtord, cmsgs: ids }, function(result){
    var vpretable = $( result ).filter('#prepend');
    var vappend = $( result ).filter('#append');
    $('#MailList tbody').prepend(vpretable);
    $('#MailList tbody').append(vappend);
    $('#loading').css({"display":"none"});      
});
```

when I do this the full table is inserted which doesn’t line-up with the table headers as this inserts a table inside a table which is not what I am looking for.

Any help or advice would be greatful

Vip32
}

Comment: Try `$('#MailList tbody').prepend(vpretable.find('tr')); $('#MailList tbody').append(vappend.find('tr'));`

Comment: thanks. something so simple worked a treat.